# How does ffmpeg record -timecode in different file formats?

Tags: ffmpeg, file-formats, timecode

As a followup to [Add timecode information to file](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/25082/add-timecode-information-to-file/25115#25115)

ffmpeg documents the `-timecode` parameter:

> -timecode hh:mm:ssSEPff
>
> Specify Timecode for writing. SEP is ’:’ for non drop timecode and ’;’ (or ’.’) for drop.

Two questions come up:

1. Which container formats support the `-timecode` option? Are there any that don't?
2. The option to specify DF/NDF timecode implies the ability to store DF flag in the file alongside the framerate. Is that how it works, or does ffmpeg convert DF timecode to a corresponding NDF frame count and stores that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. FFmpeg only supports timecode in a limited set of formats. They are the MOV family (MOV/MP4/3GP..), MXF family, raw DV and Grass Valley GXF.
2. How the timecode is stored and flagged is specific to the format. MOV stores a DF flag, integer framerate and the timecode as a rate-adjusted integer frame index. MXF does essentially the same.